# Is the Lightning 1.7 calendar for Thunderbird not supported on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, thunderbird, lightning

[This page](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/xul-ext-lightning) makes me think that Lightning 1.7 is now unsupported on Ubuntu Lucid, but I couldn't find any official announce about it... Moreover, I can't find a way to a question to the team :( So, is Lightning officially unsupported or is it just an overlook?

Comment: Whoops, looks like I forgot to upload this to the thunderbird stable PPA, doing so now.

Comment: @micahg: sorry, could it be that the same happened for version 1.8? :)

Comment: Yeah, I'll be uploading that to lucid-backports later tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per micahg's comment, it was just a simple oversight :)

*As micahhg said:*

> Whoops, looks like I forgot to upload this to the thunderbird stable PPA, doing so now.